# How to get value of input form using modal dialog boostrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having problem when I want to retrieve a value from following form input. Can you tell me a way to retrieve value from input form if in modal dialog using `onclick` event ?

```js
function add_rute(x, y) {
  var hari = $("input[name=hari]").val();
  var rute = $("input[name=rute]").val();
  console.log(hari);
}
```

```html
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM  LTSUB_itin order by id ASC";
  $rs = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
?>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo $row['id']  ?>">
    <i class="far fa-calendar-plus"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ADD DAY ID :
            <?php echo  $row['id'] ?>
          </h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <label for="hari">day </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hari" name="hari" placeholder="Select Day">
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <label for="rutet">Rute</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rute" name="rute" placeholder="rute">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="add_rute(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>,<?php echo $row['master_id'] ?>)">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `onclick`, or any of the other `onX` event attributes in your HTML. They are not good practice.

In addition, if you're using a loop to create repeated content, do not put `id` attributes in the HTML within that loop. `id` **must** be unique. Use a `class` on those elements instead.

The modern approach to do what you require is to attach your events unobtrusively and use the reference to the Element which raised that event to travers the DOM to find the related `input` you want to get the values from.

If you need to know the `id` and `master_id` associated with the entity in your PHP loop, then you can apply those values as `data` attributes in the HTML. Something like this:

```html
<!-- within the PHP loop: -->
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-master-id="<?php echo $row['master_id'] ?>">Submit</button>
</div>
```

```js
$('.submit').on('click', e => {
  const $button = $(e.target);
  const $modalBody = $button.closest('.modal-footer').prev('.modal-body');
  const id = $button.data('id');
  const masterId = $button.data('master-id');
  const hari = $modalBody.find('.hari').val();
  const rute = $modalBody.find('.rute').val();

  // work with the values here:
  console.log(id, masterId, hari, rute);
});
```

Comment: submit button not working, do you know why ?

Comment: Check the console for errors and ensure that jQuery is being loaded and that you've put your code in a document.ready handler.

Comment: its' work thankyou mr @Rory McCrossan